# Date to Month in R data

Tags: r, date, numeric

I have one `column(date)` in numeric format. I want to extract date in the format of `(day, month)` from numeric numbers in the table. The table name in *ABC* and column name is `Date`.

*Date(sample)*

```
95.00000
95.08333
95.16667
95.25000
95.33333
95.41667
```

**Q**: Shall I first convert numeric numbers to date class and then extract date?
Can anyone help with this?

Comment: What is the expected output for the sample data?

Comment: Maybe `lubridate::date_decimal(95.00000)` ?

Comment: @SvenHohenstein I want month out of the sample data.

Comment: @zx8754 this worked for me, thanks, but what if i want to convert full column not only one value. In that case date_decimal is not taking table value

Comment: Then we apply it to column, something like: `myData$myColumn <- lubridate::date_decimal(myData$myColumn)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick in base R :

```
format(as.Date(as.numeric(Sys.Date()), origin = "1970-01-01"), "(%d, %m)")
#(26, 02)
```